# zXing 2.2 giving wrong result when scan, same type of 1D barcode multiple times. Any suggestion?

Tags: zxing

Getting wrong value for the 1D barcode  (code-128 & code 39) if scan multiple times.

Using iPhone for scanning. It is more frequent on iPhone 5.

Additional info:
For one of the barcode (code 128) , while scanning it for 30 times we got
Barcode type 5 (Code -128) 28 times.  And correct barcode 27 times. 
2 times the barcode type was 16( UPC) with wrong values.
so in a trial of 30 times we got 3 times wrong values and 27 times correct values. 
The occurrence is random.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a false positive. You should not scan for UPC-E if you know you are looking for Code-128. You can re-port the Java code which may be more recent, or re-tune it. But in general this is going to happen if you scan slightly different images enough times.

Comment: Ownen: What do you mean by "scan slightly different images"?

Comment: If you are using your phone camera to scan a barcode, it's seeing slightly different images every frame even pointing at the same barcode (or anything). There's always a small false-positive possibility, so eventually you will scan a barcode in even your carpet.